# Radio button selected index not working

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist, selectedindex

So I have a sipme ASP.NET Web Page that prints the info of one's gender stacked dynamically in a radio button list:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] genders = new String[2];
    genders[0] = "Male";
    genders[1] = "Female";
    RadioButtonList1.DataSource = genders;
    RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
    RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Neutral", "Zero"));
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblName.Text = txtName.Text;
    lblSurname.Text = txtSurname.Text;
    lblEmail.Text = txtMail.Text;
    Panel1.Visible = true;
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex==0) lblGender.Text = "Male";
    else lblGender.Text = "Female";
}
```

However when I launch the site no matter what I select it always writes female it's like the RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex==0 isn't working.

Any ideas?

Comment: If nothing is happening (this does happen), cut the `Button1_Click` code out of the code-behind page and double-click the button on the design screen to recreate the click event in code-behind, then paste your code back in.

Answer (score 1):

Bind `radiobuttonlist` in `page_Load` with `!IsPostBack` condition or your `radiobuttonlist` will bind every time you post your page. So your `radiobuttonlist` is reset to index `-1` when you click the `button_click`.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            String[] genders = new String[2];
            genders[0] = "Male";
            genders[1] = "Female";
            RadioButtonList1.DataSource = genders;
            RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
            RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Neutral", "Zero"));
        }
    }
```